# What causes inconsistent SQL 2K backups?

Tags: backup, sql-server, restore

I take weekly full backups of a SQL 2000 database via vanilla Enterprise Manager.

The problem happened when I tried to restore the database. I learn that it was not up-to-date as it was pointing back to a month old data, I even double checked the other 2 weekly backups and the data was almost identical. Is there any technical explanation or known MS bug for that. Kindly note that the database server was running on a RAID5 HDD configuration and one of these hard disks was faulty. Moreover, all of the weekly backups have different sizes and of course a file datestamp.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you backing up each week appending to the same backup file or to a separate physical file each time.

Comment: I overwrite the old backup file..I take tape backups of the existing backup. backup of the backup

Answer (score 1):

Something had to have gone wrong with the backup, or the wrong file was restored.  Perhaps you had more than one backup within the backup file?

It isn't possible for SQL Server to backup a database and have the database in the backup be older than the current set of data.

The only exception would be if you had a transaction open for months, and then the database is backed up, then when restored the transaction would then be rolled back.